# Create proportion bar plot with dodge position

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create the following plot but with **proportion** on the y axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = clarity), position = "dodge")
```

but when I add `y=..prop..`, it doesn't group it by `clarity`. I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
      geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., fill = clarity), position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate *proportion* (or *frequency*) you can use `..count..` (proportion is specific `count` divided by all `count`'s):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, (..count..) / sum(..count..), fill = clarity)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried this but I was adding `group = 1`. Thank you!

Comment: @chintans I know. For some reason `..prob..` with `dodge` and `group = 1` doesn't work.